# Django rest-framework session timeout

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-sessions

In a rest-api I have used *django rest-framework*. For authentication I have done:

```py
    if username is not None and password is not None:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                if not created:
                    token.created =     datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
                    token.save()
                login(request, user)
                return Response({'token': token.key, 'username': user.username})
            else:
                return Response({'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
        else:
            return Response({'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
    else:
        return Response({'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
```

And for logout:

```py
    token = Token.objects.get(key=request.data.get('token'))
    token.delete()
    logout(request)
    return Response({'status': status.HTTP_200_OK}
```

In *settings.py* Permission classes and Authentication classes are:

```py
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
```

A request comes with the token included. And I have set the ideal timeout 10 minutes in angularjs.

The problem is after sometime, even if its not ideal, for each requests, rest-framework responses an authentication problem. I guess, its because of the session timeout of the rest-framework.

So, Can any one suggest a path to resolve this problem or, to set the default session timeout interval manually in *django rest-framework*?

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: "Responds an authentication problem"? How? What exactly is the response? Have you set up [custom session expiry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) (the default is 2 weeks)?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have not set up any custom session expiry. Still, I get 401 error.

Comment: where do you store your token in client side (angular)? localStorage? cookie? where?